# Why can't I use Clouds EX ability?

Tags: dissidia-final-fantasy-opera-omnia

In the lastest draw I managed to get my first EX Weapon for Cloud. Which adds the Meteorain ability.

When I go into battle the ability never highlights as usable. You can see an example in the attached image, where the ability is shown in dark red. Tapping this does nothing.

[image: Battle with Clouds abilities listed]

How can I use this ability? Are there prerequisites for the weapon such as limit breaks or experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems these abilities are on a turn timer, and become active after a certain number of turns. This is indicated by a circular line around the EX icon, which fills as the ability charges.

When I encountered a longer 3 wave battle, in the last wave the ability was active and I could use it.